# Can't find element by name using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm using `selenium 4.7.2` and can't find the element by its name. The following code returns `NoSuchElementException` error:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Get the website using the Chrome webbdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.woofshack.com/en/cloud-chaser-waterproof-softshell-dog-jacket-ruffwear-rw-5102.html')

# Print out the result
price = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'data-price-665')
print("Price: " + price.text)

# Close the browser
time.sleep(3)
browser.close()
```

What's wrong in using `find_element` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using a wrong locator here. I see no element with `name` attribute value `'data-price-665'` on that page.
The following code is working:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

url = "https://www.woofshack.com/en/cloud-chaser-waterproof-softshell-dog-jacket-ruffwear-rw-5102.html"
driver.get(url)

price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#product-price-665 .price")))
print("Price: " + price.text)
```

The output is:

```
Price: €112.95
```

Comment: You are more than welcome!